# Get textbox text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date

I have a textbox which accepts date values like **01-01-2013**. I need to get the year in javascript. This is the code I have used:

```
var oldRange, aOldRange;  
var newRange, aNewRange;  
aoldRange = new Array();  
anewRange = new Array();  
var oldYear, newYear;  
oldRange = document.getElementById(
                       '<%= txtAcademicYearStartDate.ClientID%>').value;
aOldRange = oldRange.split("-");
oldYear = aoldRange[2];
```

But I get the value as undefined. What's the issue?

Comment: You are using `aOldRange`, but refering to `oldYear = aoldRange[2]`

Comment: are u getting `oldRange` correctly?

Comment: Have solved, changed aoldRange to OldRange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined `aOldRange`, but refering to `oldYear = aoldRange[2]`

try

```
oldYear = aOldRange[2]
```

Comment: Yeah, sick of me. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

This example is tested and working fine please refer

```
<script language="javascript" >         
    var oldRange, aOldRange;
    var newRange, aNewRange;
    aoldRange = new Array();
    anewRange = new Array();
    var oldYear, newYear;
    oldRange = '01-01-2013'; 
    aOldRange = oldRange.split("-"); 
    alert(aOldRange[2]);
</script>
```